# How to add the author name when sharing on Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm just trying to add the name of the author in the share box dialog in FB

[image]

I've added the following meta and og property:

```
<meta name="author" content="foutight.com">   
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:article:author" content="foutight.com"/>
```

But no success. Any suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That comes from the `<meta name='author' content='...'/>` section. It looks like it's appearing on http://foutight.com/posts/photo/242 - maybe you've just got a cached page?

Run it through oglint.com, and try and re-scrape it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the author whitout the "og".

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/> 
<meta property="article:author" content="foutight.com"/>
```

Comment: Tried but same result.

Comment: Facebook takes some time to process Open Graph maybe if you try it later.
I'm not able to test this on facebook right now, but you could try looking it up on Facebook Developer Debug Tool.
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta name="author" content="foutight.com"> 
<meta property="article:author" content="https://www.facebook.com/author_profile" />
```

article:author  may contain an array of Facebook profile URLs or IDs of the authors for this article.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/article/

Answer (score -2):

Open function.php and add code :

```
function author_chauit() {
if ( is_singular('post') ) {
echo '<meta name="author" content="'.get_the_author().'">';
} else {
echo '<meta name="author" content="'.get_bloginfo( 'name' ).'">';
}
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'author_chauit' );
```

notes : add in end functioncode

Comment: This is not a Wordpress question.